# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting based on other cell being empty and not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

If cell A4 is not empty, I want conditional formatting to be applied to cells B4, C4 and D4 (making them red, prompting the user to fill those cells). Then when cells B4, C4 and D4 are not empty I want to overwrite the red formatting with grey (indicating that they have filled all the required cells).

This is the closest I've come: [example of formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI1Uu.png)

I'm working with =NOT(ISBLANK($A$4)) but I don't want column B, C and D to be red when column A is empty.

Also it should apply to every row but looking at column A for that specific row number:
A5 -> B5,C5,D5
A6 -> B6,C6,D6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

*Apply to range*: `B4:D`

***red** formatting custom formula*: `=len($A4)*(counta($B4:$D4)<3)`

***grey** formatting custom formula*: `=len($A4)*(counta($B4:$D4)=3)`

[image]